# How can I write my own R cumsum() function?

Tags: r, cumulative-sum, cumsum

I am so new in R and want to write ****my own R cumsum()** function**. How can I create the function which takes in a length N vector of values to compute cumulative sums.
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to write that specific function, or a function in general? If the former, what is your purpose of doing that instead of just using `cumsum()`?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Right now this isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.  If you are new to R, i'd recommend not trying to re-create optimized built in base functions. It's better to just use the existing function. If this is homework for some class or something, you could contact your instructor for guidance.

Comment: Following @MrFlick: if this is homework and you *don't* want to contact your instructor for whatever reason, you should show us how what you've tried to get started. See e.g. [this question on asking HW questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cumsum function using `accumulate` from the `{purrr}` package:

```
alt_cumsum <- function(x) {
  require(purrr)
  accumulate(x, `+`)
}
```

Example usage:

```
> alt_cumsum(1:5)
[1]  1  3  6 10 15
```